# Video HTML5 Quitar modo "imagen sobre imagen"

Tags: html, html5, html-video

nunca había visto esto, ahora en Mozilla Firefox me aparece un botón en el vídeo que  pone "Imagen sobre imagen", al pulsar, convierte el vídeo en un vídeo flotante y en el lugar originar ahora pone "Este vídeo se está reproduciendo en modo de imagen sobre imagen".
Me gustaría saber como desactivar esta característica ya que para mi propósito actual esto no puede aparecer.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Que visualizador estás usando?

Comment: Visualizador? No sé que es eso... Como puedo comprobarlo?

Comment: Estás usando alguna librería para mostrar el vídeo o es sólo un elemento html? puedes añadir como pintas el vídeo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta funcionalidad es nueva para los navegadores y se añade automáticamente a los vídeos.

Puedes desactivarla usando el atributo `disablePictureInPicture`, pero Firefox de momento (a día 31 de Julio de 2020) no lo ha implementado.En MDN está marcado como [*experimental*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-disablePictureInPicture)